# setAnimationListener for AnimationUtils animation reset?

Tags: android, animation

I'm using animations on a viewflipper and loading them like AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flipout);

the problem is that I'm also setting AnimationListener on them and would like it to set different listeners at different times. The problem is that they retain the animationlistener from the previous time they were loaded with loadAnimation and setting a new animation listener on them does nothing(doesn't crash either, the new animation listener just never gets called).

do I have to just abandon AnimationUtils.loadAnimation and create new animation objects myself? can I disable it's caching?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

the answer is quite simply that I was calling myviewflipper.showPrevious(); before setting the new animations to the viewflipper that was using them, even if that piece of ui thread didn't return before they were set. so viewflipper does it with the animations that are set when you call previous/next - not the one's that are set after it even if it doesn't have oppurtunity to start showing them.